# Converting the Data Type of Pandas Column

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

If the values in a Pandas DataFrame column `timestampMs` is of type `unicode`, and we want to convert it to a `float`, is there any difference between the following 2 methods?

```
df['timestampMs'].map(lambda x: float(x)/1000)
```

and

```
df['timestampMs'].astype('float')/1000
```

Since they both seem to give the same results, which is the preferred method?

Comment: Read this https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/a7437430b5cb62e49a79b64d18eccfb2b4d6367f/pandas/core/internals.py#L375 and decide appropraitely dependent upon on your criteria for 'preferred' method. Your first example will fail if one value is '-' for example.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm... if you care about speed the lambda method is a tiny bit faster for small datasets. For large datasets go for the `.astype()` method (I also personally find it more readable):

```
import time
import timeit
import pandas as pd

num_elements = 100
times = [unicode(time.clock()) for x in range(num_elements)]

df = pd.DataFrame(times)

def first_method():
    df[0].map(lambda x: float(x)/1000)

def second_method():
    df[0].astype('float')/1000

num_reps = 15000

print("First method time for {} reps: {}".format(num_reps, timeit.timeit(first_method, number=num_reps)))
print("Second method time for {} reps: {}".format(num_reps, timeit.timeit(second_method, number=num_reps)))
```

When `num_elements = 100` I get:

```
First method time for 15000 reps: 1.95685731342
Second method time for 15000 reps: 2.22381265566
```

When `num_elements = 1000` I get:

```
First method time for 15000 reps: 12.0774245498
Second method time for 15000 reps: 6.77670391568
```